# Does GCC11 have a regression in which it incorrectly accept pointer to array of abstract class

Tags: c++, g++, abstract-class

In GCC 4 to 10 and Clang (all versions), this piece of code does not compile because the compiler is unable to allocate memory for A because A is abstract:

```
class A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

void f(A (*)[1]) {}
```

However, in GCC11+ this appears to compile successfully.

This idiom is useful for detecting an abstract class before C++11 and Boost indeed uses this for their [type_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp) library.

Did I miss something or is this a regression in the compiler?

Comment: I don't think the standard would bother disable such declaration, maybe it's just not defined? (and both are correct)

Comment: btw the code doesn't allocate array of pointer, it's a single pointer to an array.

Comment: I did not understand the significance of the parentheses around the (*) until today. Learned something new, thank you.

Question title edited to reflect this new understanding.

Comment: @HoCheung that's still not correct, a pointer would not allocate anything (except the pointer itself).

Comment: I'm not understanding. How would you word this?

Comment: @HoCheung fwiw it's not only happens in parameter https://godbolt.org/z/x9zW67jnv

Comment: @HoCheung title edited, the point is a pointer doesn't allocate any array, so say it does would be incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[P0929R2](https://wg21.link/P0929R2) changed the rules so that it's no longer ill-formed to mention the type "array of `X`" where `X` is an abstract class type. (Of course, such a type can never be instantiated.) This change was made because it was sort of silly that you were allowed to mention the "array of `X`" type when `X` is incomplete, only to later define `X` as an abstract class type and thus trigger a compilation error at the point of definition.

Because this change was approved as a Defect Report in the Rapperswil meeting (June 2018), newer versions of compilers should apply the new rules in all language versions (which in this case means all the way back to C++98).